# Segue programmatically does not work in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have been trying to perform a segue programmatically by doing:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnRedirect: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToSecond", sender: btnRedirect)
    }

    @IBAction func redirect(sender: AnyObject) {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToSecond", sender: self)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the segue works perfectly by clicking in the button to perform it although when I try to do it programmatically as you can see inside the `viewDidLoad` method, it does not work!

I've already tried to pass `sender` as `nil`.

Comment: You can't perform a segue in `viewDidLoad`, do it in `viewDidAppear` if you want to do it as soon as the view comes on screen

Comment: we get it, your question is about Swift. no need FOR THE ALL CAPS.

Comment: Code updated.let me know what you thing...

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326516/xcode-swift-3-timer-and-segue-view-controller-error/40326611#40326611

Answer (score 0):

As **dan'S** comment you can't perform segue in ViewDidLoad do it in viewDidAppears.?

**Note:** Move perform segue from your ViewDidLoad to viewDidAppers or **inside your button Action as below code** and make sure you set your segue identifier in storyBoard to "segueToSecond".Untested code.So,let me know.if you have any trouble executing.

**Updated:**

**Note:** If you want your segue perform automatically after view loads. you should connect segue from VC to VC.

```
      @IBAction func redirect(sender: AnyObject) {
     segueToSecondVC()
}


      func segueToSecondVC() {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToSecond", sender: self)
  }

      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if (segue.identifier == "segueToSecond") {

       let dest = segue.destination as! viewTwo // viewTwo is your destination ViewController
       print("Segue Performed")

   }

  }
```

**Updated:**

**Note:** If you want the segue perform automatilcally after view loads you can setup some delay to your segue from below code.

```
     let delayInSeconds = 4.0
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {

    segueToSecondVC()

  }

  }
```

Hope this help you to resolve the issue....

Comment: There's no need to implement prepare for segue method in this example.

Comment: He wanna do it programmically mate.look at my note at the bottom of my answer.