# Xcode doesn't Recognise Timer()- Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, timer

New to Swift here- I'm trying to achieve a simple segue operation after predefined times lapses. But for some reason my Xcode isn't recognizing the `Timer` and gives error "Timer module has no member named scheduledTimer". I couldn't find help anywhere.

CODE:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let emptystring = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var time = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 8.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeview), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func changeview (){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToMain", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "GoToMain"){
            let destination = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! SecondView
            destination.emptyString = emptystring
        }
        print("Segue Performed")
    }

}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQBbH.jpg) also shows my entire code, including the error. NOTE: It's not my own code. I only followed the answer to question in following link:

[Xcode Swift 3: Timer and Segue View Controller Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326516/xcode-swift-3-timer-and-segue-view-controller-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timer` is a Swift 3 type, but judging from the rest of your method signatures, you appear to be using Swift 2. Use `NSTimer` in Swift 2.

---

Also, for future reference, in addition to the `timeInterval` typo (which you've now fixed), the third parameter is `selector`, not `selecter`.

---

So, in Swift 2:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeview), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Or in Swift 3:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 8.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeview), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Even with NSTimer it repeats the same error. p.s: I extremely apologie for the silly mistakes

Comment: @ZairaZafar See Swift 2 and Swift 3 renditions in revised answer above. Note, if you have troubles when cutting and pasting code you find on Stack Overflow in the future, comment out the pasted code and try typing it yourself and rely on "code completion" to get the right syntax, labels, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps!

Comment: I apologise. I just didn't know how. Just accepted your answer. Thank you Rob for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the first parameter as `timerInterval` but it should be `timeInterval` instead.

So change:

```
var time = Timer.scheduledTimer(timerInterval: 8.0, target: self, selecter: #selector(changeview), userInfo: nil, repeats: false
```

To:

```
var time = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 8.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeview), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: If this question is the result of a typo, vote to close the question with the reason "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**." instead of answering.

Comment: Edited it. The error still persists. If it was an argument issue, incorrect argument would have been highlighted. P.s: though thank you for the above fix

Answer (score 0):

Also note that with Swift 4, you have to add @objc to the selector you call after the timer expires, because the code that calls this selector is apparently still written in Objective-C.

So change:

```
func changeview()
```

to this:

```
@objc func changeview()
```